# Why would my Project properties Target Device disagree with the Target Platform?

Tags: windows-ce, platform, pocketpc, handheld, target-platform

In a Windows CE project, when I select Project > Change Target Platform, it says that the Current Platform is Windows CE.

However, in Project Properties, although Platform == the same ("Windows CE"), the Target Device property value is "Pocket PC 2003 SE Emulator" (although one of the many options in the dropdown is "Windows CE Device"

Is this a mismatch? Should I change the Target Device to match the Platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each SDK (Target Platform) can install its own "devices". A device definition simply configures how the debugger will connect to the device and where the exe file is deployed by default. You can have multiple devices for each SDK and also deploy your app to a device that is not connected to the SDK you are using to build the application, that's why the dev environment does not force you to use a device that is connected to a specific SDK.